# What is the difference between "in a bit, shortly, soon" vs "later"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

When texting via Instant Messaging apps, what would be appropriate to say when we do not intend to respond to the other person?  "in a bit, shortly, soon" vs "later" - The first three phrases here literally mean the same thing and mostly interchangeable compared to the phrase "later".

Can we use all of them interchangeably?

Would it be a mistake to say I'll respond to you shortly/soon/in a bit and take days to respond? Can we substitute the phrase "later" in this context?

Comment: The meaning of all these expressions is vague and really depends on what your timescale is, but I would suggest that _later_ implies an intention, or expectation, that there will be a lapse of time before you do it.